# JavaScript fallback for vh CSS unit not working in iOS 7

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've got a section on a website that uses the `vh` CSS unit for its height when the browser is landscape and <600px. Its done like below.

```
#section1 {
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
}


@media (max-height: 599px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #section1 {
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but iOS 7 doesn't work with the `vh` unit. So for this I was trying to implement a JavaScript work around. I've managed to get together the following, but I am struggling to see where to tell it only to kick in at < 600px on a landscape device like my media query above does, any ideas?

```
// IOS7 VH FIX
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
var isMobileSafari = /(iPhone|iPod|iPad).+AppleWebKit/i.test(userAgent) && (function() {
        var iOSversion = userAgent.match(/OS (\d)/);
        // viewport units work fine in mobile Safari and webView on iOS 8+
        return iOSversion && iOSversion.length>1 && parseInt(iOSversion[1]) < 8;
    })();
if (isMobileSafari) {
    var setSliderHeight = function() {
        $("#section1").css('height', Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0) + 'px');
    };
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
        setSliderHeight();
    });
    setSliderHeight();
};
```